# Why does str_match not capture group the same way regex101 does?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have this string:

```
bn = "this_is_a_test_12345.txt"
```

And I want to capture/extract the numeric part (`12345`). Trying it on regex101.com works like this:

[image]

Yet doing it in R does not work that way:

```
str_match(bn, ".*(\\d*).*") # works not

str_match(bn, ".*_(\\d*).*") # works (second column is the matched group)
```

I think I am missing something very simple about greediness or so, but I am not sure...

Comment: Non greedy `.*?(\\d+).*`  should work

Comment: Use `str_extract(bn, '\\d+')` instead

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you will need the non greedy pattern as captured with `?`:

```
sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", bn)
# [1] "12345"
```